# How to use siblings method on variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

I have several divs in my variable `offers` and I want to call siblings method on them so as to slide down the first three divs having class `notspecialoffer`.Initially these all `notspecialoffer` divs are hidden.
For Example `offers` variable contain these divs:

```
<div class="special">A</div>
<div class="notspecial">B</div>
<div class="notspecial">C</div>
<div class="notspecial">D</div>
```

What will be the appropriate jquery code? Something like:

```
$().siblings("div.notspecialoffer:lt(3)").slideDown();
```

Comment: something like that yea, but not exactly. don't you think you might be missing something here? `$()` you might not even need .siblings.

Comment: Oh well I got it from your hint! I just simply used `$("div.notspecialoffer:lt(3)").slideDown();` and it works! :)